# KABOOM! UNDEFINED-COLUMN: Database error 42703: column does not exist

Tags: mysql, postgresql, ubuntu, pgloader

I am having a very difficult time getting pgloader to convert a mysql to postgres on one specific database.

I get the following error message when running pgloader

```
[root@38AA08C pgsql]# pgloader pg_load
2023-06-21T03:13:59.006000+01:00 LOG pgloader version "3.6.7~devel"
2023-06-21T03:13:59.893030+01:00 LOG Migrating from #<MYSQL-CONNECTION mysql://******* {10068EB193}>
2023-06-21T03:13:59.893030+01:00 LOG Migrating into #<PGSQL-CONNECTION pgsql://******* {10068EB333}>
KABOOM!
UNDEFINED-COLUMN: Database error 42703: column ""output_ID"" of relation "hir_2016_model_assessment" does not exist
CONTEXT: PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 6 at FOR over SELECT rows
QUERY:
DO $$
DECLARE
  n integer := 0;
  r record;
BEGIN
  FOR r in
       SELECT 'select '
               || trim(trailing ')'
```

As you can see, the column does exist

```
                                                                       Table "public.hir_2016_model_assessment"
         Column         |      Type      | Collation | Nullable |                            Default                             | Storage | Compression | Stats target | Description
------------------------+----------------+-----------+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------+---------+-------------+--------------+-------------
 output_ID              | bigint         |           | not null | nextval('"hir_2016_model_assessment_output_ID_seq"'::regclass) | plain   |             |              |
 project_ID             | integer        |           | not null |                                                                | plain   |             |              |
```

My load file looks like this

```
LOAD DATABASE
   FROM      mysql://*****
   INTO postgresql://*****
   alter schema 'regen' rename to 'public'

   WITH
      include drop, create tables, create indexes, reset sequences, schema only, quote identifiers,
      multiple readers per thread, rows per range = 50000

   SET PostgreSQL PARAMETERS
      maintenance_work_mem to '1GB'

   SET MySQL PARAMETERS
      net_read_timeout  = '31536000',
      net_write_timeout = '31536000',
      lock_wait_timeout = '31536000'

   CAST
      type enum to text drop not null using empty-string-to-null,
      type date drop not null drop default using zero-dates-to-null,
      type datetime to timestamp drop default using zero-dates-to-null,
      type bigint when unsigned to numeric drop typemod,
      type bigint when (<= precision 20) to bigint drop typemod,
      type geography to bytea,
      type geometry  to point using convert-mysql-point,
      type point     to point using convert-mysql-point

   -- BEFORE LOAD DO
      -- $$ create extension if not exists postgis; $$
;
```

I have been struggling with this all day long. Any clues what could be causing this to fail?

Comment: Is it not complaining about the MySQL end of the transfer? It fails while selecting data rather than inserting

Comment: @RichardHuxton, where are you seeing that? I see it failing on a `plpgsql` DO function which indicates to me it is on the Postgres side of the migration.

Comment: Not a pgloader user, so don't know how it operates. But given that we can see the column on the PG side and it failed during a SELECT I was prepared to guess some foreign-data-wrapper/dblink stuff going on. I mean it could be search_path but the table is in the "public" schema and the column might have a space on the end, but that seems unlikely too.

Comment: So I did some more digging around. And I ran the process again. The postgres side of the migration has the same number of tables as the mysql source. However, looking furthure into the errors which I will display entire output, it is trying to do a select from reloid which does not exist.